# NPM Datacomb error

Tags: node.js, npm

I am getting this error when trying to run `npm run serve` in my datacomb directory: `./node_modules/serve/bin/serve -p 5050 '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

I have the leastest version of npm/nodejs and had the latest version of [datacomb](https://github.com/cmpolis/datacomb)
but was getting this same error, so I downgraded to datacomb V1.0.0 and I am still getting this error. Any ideas on what's going on?

```
    > ./node_modules/serve/bin/serve -p 5050

'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "serve"
npm ERR! node v5.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! datacomb@1.0.0 serve: `./node_modules/serve/bin/serve -p 5050`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the datacomb@1.0.0 serve script './node_modules/serv
ve -p 5050'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm insta
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the datacomb pac
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     ./node_modules/serve/bin/serve -p 5050
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls datacomb
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\hstrozier\Documents\datacomb-1.0.0\npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in the datacomb files. Workaround:

```
1.  Run: $ node "C:\path\to\datacomb-master\node_modules\serve-it\server.js" 
2.  You will be prompted for a path to the directory that you’d like to serve and a port. Insert: 

prompt: path:  C:\path\to\datacomb-master
prompt: port:  5050
Serving C:\path\

to\datacomb-master on port: 5050
```